# Does the probability that an electron absorbs a photon change with the distance between the two?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

Suppose there is an electron and a photon. For simplicity, no other forces are influencing the particles. Does the probability that the electron absorbs a photon change if the photon moves to a different location?

I understand my terminology is not exact. Please keep in mind what I’m asking and don’t get wrapped up in the details. This is a true/false question. This isn’t a mathematical question; it’s a physics question.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I’ve edited the question to be more accurate.

Comment: Are you more likely to see to see Betelgeuse if you are 100000 km away from it, or if you are on Earth?

Comment: @StudyStudy You will vaporize before you get there. Its diameter is 120 million kilometers.

Comment: Your title says “electron absorbs an *electron*”.

Comment: I’m sorry, I made a typo. Thanks

Comment: " For simplicity, no other forces are influencing the particles." - What other forces are there? And what is that one force you refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A photon has *zero* probability of being absorbed or emitted by an electron unless they are at the same point at the same time. QED is a theory where all direct interactions are *local*. The whole point of introducing the electromagnetic field was to eliminate action-at-a-distance between charged particles.

Comment: So the probability for absorption is 0 unless the electron and photon are at the exact same position in space-time. Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know what you mean by a shrinking factor. Each local interaction between an electron and a photon contributes a factor of $\alpha$, the fine structure constant, to the probability of whatever process you are calculating.

Comment: I was discussing Feynman diagrams. I removed that part of the question because it wasn’t relevant and it didn’t make sense.

Comment: I see you deleted the part about the shrinking factor. I agree with what you wrote after your edit.

Comment: Yes, each vertex contributes a factor of $e$ (electron charge) to the probability amplitude, or $\alpha$ to the probability.

Answer (score 0):

Free electrons do not absorb photons. Energy-momentum conservation forbids it. Free electrons can scatter photons. This is known as Compton scattering.

A photon does not exert a force on an electron. To locate a photon you need to absorb or scatter it. It can only be absorbed where it is.

I would not call this a true/false question. Physics questions rarely are.

Comment: It isn’t necessarily a free electron. I edited the question to show that. I’ll accept this if it answers the question.